# Access Web API(Nodejs) using ROPC Azure B2C flow (Without browser login)

Tags: node.js, azure-ad-b2c

I have Web API which is an NodeJs code. In Web API we have protect API using (passport.authenticate('oauth-bearer', {session: false}).

When generating token using ROPC app in postman, Access token is generated but at the time of authorization

```
var bearerStrategy = new BearerStrategy(options,
function (token, done) {
  console.log(options);
  console.log(token);
  
    // Send user info using the second argument
    done(null, {}, token);
}
```

);

This will return unauthorized.

I have added scope and configure Native and Web API as per document.

Comment: Can you please provide the document that  you are referring

Comment: You can get access token using curl for ROPC `curl -X POST -d "client_id=Clientid&scope=openid+appid+offline_access&grant_type=password&username=username&password=password&response_type=token" https://<tenant-name>.b2clogin.com/<tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_ROPC_Auth/oauth2/v2.0/token'

Comment: Parse your token and provide screenshots.

Comment: Thank you Sruthi the curl solves my issue.

Comment: I was using old origin url which is login.microsoftonline.com after replacing with  <tenant-name>.b2clogin.com it works

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved by @Sruthi comment, add it as the answer to close the question:

> For `login.microsoftonline.com`, it is generally used to perform a
> login request for **Azure ad** tenants to obtain tokens. For **b2c**
> tenants, you need to use `tenant-name.b2clogin.com` to perform the
> request.
>
> Use [ROPC flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-ropc?tabs=app-reg-ga) to get access token:
>
> ```
> POST https://<tenant-name>.b2clogin.com/<tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_ROPC_Auth/oauth2/v2.0/token
>
> username=<username>
> &password=<Passxword>
> &grant_type=password
> &scope=openid+app_id+offline_access
> &client_id=<client_id>
> &response_type=token+id_token
> ```

Answer (score 0):

(Moving from comments to Answer).

You can get access token using curl for ROPC `curl -X POST -d "client_id=Clientid&scope=openid+appid+offline_access&grant_type=password&username=username&password=password&response_type=token" https://<tenant-name>.b2clogin.com/<tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_ROPC_Auth/oauth2/v2.0/token'`

As you are using old origin URL which is `login.microsoftonline.com` should no longer refer to your applications and APIs. Instead, use `b2clogin.com` for all new applications, and migrate existing applications from login.microsoftonline.com to b2clogin.com. Please refer to the official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/b2clogin)